# OpenId Connect client architecture for Isomorphic React apps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, openid-connect, isomorphic-javascript

I am working on a big microservices based project with business features distributed over various microservices. My concern is with the front-end which is being implemented as an **isomorphic react redux spa app**.

We have implemented an **OpenId Connect Provider**(Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET Core) for Single Sign On functionality as our core business features can be accessed by third-party apps from our clients.

My **first question** is what is the **best/most suited flow and architecture** to implement opened connect in an **isomorphic react app** as the app can work both server side and in the browser.

Currently we are using the **Implicit Flow**(as suggested by the spec for browser based JavaScript apps) to get the Id token and the Access token, however due to nature of the Implicit Flow these tokens are returned directly to the browser and are thus exposed publicly.

I am confused about the **Hybrid flow** and if it can be used(whether it is advisable) here to retrieve the access token at the server in case of an isomorphic app.

My **second question** is that in a **react redux scenario** what is the best way to **store the tokens** so that they can be used both at the client and server side. If I store it in browser local storage/session store it would not be available at the server. Is it good idea to store the tokens in the redux store??

Looking forward for valuable guidance.

Comment: Well, what I understand about isomorphic apps is that the first request made by the web browser is processed by the server while subsequent requests are processed by the client. And also we can load any page directly from the server any time if requested to the server. But in essence the app is still primarily executing as a browser based JavaScript app, so according to the opened spec it should use the implicit flow. However I would like to hear from the experts about this scenario and possible solutions.

Comment: Have you found any solution to your question? I'm interested in this because using the react & redux template for .NET Core caused some problems for me when i used this package: https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc